# Paste0 weird behaviour

Tags: r, paste

Cant for the life of me figure out why this happens, another analyst has looked over this as well and is just as stumped. Probably something to do with the number of combinations but the variations I have tried havn't helped.

The syntax below recreates an example of some syntax to build an API call. I have a list of domains and a list of countries, it pulls these together to give every combination (i.e "bbc.com - UK", "bbc.com - Spain", "bbc.com - Poland". The country codes are 2 digit ISO codes, in the example below the domains are random text.

For some reason, when 112 domains are combined with 7 countries, each domain is given one country, i.e ""bbc.com - UK", "bbc.com - UK", "bbc.com - UK". If I add two more countries, as in the second example, this works. Changing the number of domains also makes it work.

```
domains <- data.frame(Domain=paste(stri_rand_strings(112, 5, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]"),".com"))

###DOES NOT WORK
country <- data.frame(country=rep(c("au","be","fr","nl","pl","ch","us"),nrow(domains)))                  

###DOES WORK
country <- data.frame(country=rep(c("au","be","fr","nl","pl","ch","us","aa","aa"),nrow(domains)))   


APICall <- paste0('https://api.abc.com/website/',domains$Domain,"/start_date=","2017-03",'&end_date=',"2018-02","&country=",country$country)
APICall <- transform(APICall,Domain=gsub(".*website/","",APICall))
APICall$Domain<- gsub("/.*","",APICall$Domain)
APICall <- transform(APICall,Country=strtrim(gsub(".*&country=","",APICall$X_data),2))
APICall <- transform(APICall,Date=strtrim(gsub(".*/start_date=","",APICall$X_data),7))
```

I have a workaround (adding the two "aa" countries), but I would really like to know whats going on...

Sys info: R 3.3.2 R Studio Version 1.0.143 OS Sierra 10_12_3

Comment: I think the reason is that in the second case, for ''aa", the frequency is double and in first one, it is just the same for all the unique elements

Comment: Sorry @akrun, don't quite get what you're saying? I played around with different numbers of domains and countries (e.g just one "aa") but couldnt find any pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to create all possible combinations, however when you use a simple `rep()` there's no guarantee you will create all possible combinations.

If you start with your two simple vectors

```
domains <- paste(stringi::stri_rand_strings(112, 5, pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]"),".com")
countries <- c("au","be","fr","nl","pl","ch","us")
```

You can get all possible combinations with `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(domains, countries)
```

or if you are using `tidyr` from the `tidyverse` packages

```
tidyr::crossing(domains, countries)
```

Just using `rep()` wont give all combinations. For example

```
x <- letters[1:10]
y <- rep(letters[21:25], length(x))
comb <- paste(x,y)
```

Note that

```
length(comb)
# [1] 50
length(unique(comb))
# [1] 10
```

So there are lot of duplicates there. If one vector length is evenly divisible by the other, the repetitions will repeat within the period of the other and you won't get all the possible combinations

Comment: This works brilliantly thank you! i wasn't aware of either of these. Thanks for the explanation as well.